# Angular4 JavaScript runtime error and SourceMap read failed

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting a lot of error on my angular2 pages, on the debug output, i can see lots of JavaScript runtime error and SourceMap read failed.

The pages are working fine, only see them in debug mode, not in the console when debug in chrome, but i think because of these errors, it slows down the page load speed.  any help appreciate ..

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 2657 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 3371 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 2657 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 3371 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 2657 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a13da - JavaScript runtime error: Typed array constructor argument is invalid
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 3371 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'
Exception was thrown at line 7, column 19118 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trimLeft'
Exception was thrown at line 7, column 19118 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trimRight'
Exception was thrown at line 9, column 6882 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '__defineSetter__' is undefined
Exception was thrown at line 1128, column 25 in http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js

SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/Observable.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/Observable.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/root.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/root.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/Subscriber.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/Subscriber.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/isFunction.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/isFunction.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/Subscription.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/Subscription.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/isArray.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/isArray.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/isObject.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/isObject.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js'. 
SourceMap http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/errorObject.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'eval code sourceUrl: http://localhost/MyWeb/Scripts/vendor/rxjs/util/errorObject.js'.
```

I suspect it is due to the packages i am using, here is my package.json, can not share the code as it's a large project "dependencies": { "@angular/animations": "~4.0.3", "@angular/common": "^4.0.0", "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0", "@angular/core": "^4.0.0", "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0", "@angular/http": "^4.0.0", "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0", "@angular/router": "^4.0.0", "@angular/upgrade": "^4.0.0", "core-js": "^2.4.1", "es6-shim": "^0.35.3", "ng2-toastr": "^4.0.1", "primeng": "^2.0.2", "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10", "rxjs": "^5.3.0", "systemjs": "^0.19.39", "zone.js": "^0.8.4" }, "devDependencies": { "gulp": "^3.9.1", "typescript": "^2.5.2", "typings": "^1.5.0", "tslint": "^5.1.0", "merge-stream": "^1.0.1", "toastr": "^2.1.2", "underscore": "^1.8.3", "angular": "^1.5.8", "jquery": "^3.2.1", "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34", "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35", "@types/angular": "1.5.8", "@types/underscore": "", "@types/node": "~6.0.60", "@types/toastr": "" } }

Comment: can you share some your code?

Comment: I suspect it is due to the packages i am using: